# How do i recursively remove folders from mercurial tracking system

Tags: mercurial

I have a working directory structure like the below one :

**mercurial_working_dir:**

- project1
- project2
- project3

Under each project folder there are common folders that i want to untrack from mercurial.e.g:
i dont want any file to be tracked under /metadata folder which is common at the 3 projects.
As far as i know i should use hg remove -Af command with the specifing files.Is there any way to define regular exps at the command in order to recursively "remove" the current version of any file under the metadata folder which is placed at all my projects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the chapter about [file names and pattern matching](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html) in the mercurial book. You can use a pattern like this:

```
hg rm "glob:**/metadata/**"
```

If you prefer regular expressions, you can also use the `re:` prefix instead of `glob:`.

Comment: Thank you.That was what i was looking for.How to include the glob or the regular expressions into a command.Very useful.